# Whats the correct way use PHP cURL for a GET request with query parameters and alternate port number? (for SOLR)

Tags: php, curl, solr

I'm trying to use PHP cURL to send a GET request to Apache Solr to receive search results, and I'm running into some trouble. This is more to do with PHP cURL I think than Solr...but i digress...here's what I have so far.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/solr/example/select?".$this->query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8983);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '4');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

curl_close($ch);
```

Currently, the request times out at 4 seconds...so I'm wondering if maybe the port# isn't being set properly...I also tried to include it in the URL itself with no luck. The weird part is that I can echo the constructed URL, add the port# manually, copy/paste into the browser and it works! But, for some reason it doesn't with the code above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to curl the url via the command line on this server? `curl "http://example.com:8983/solr/example/select"`? It will help narrow down the problem as it could be related to a network or firewall issue too.

Comment: I'll try this now. 2 minutes.

Comment: Oh boy. Yeah, doesn't work. That may be the issue. Let me turn off the firewall and see if that makes a difference real quick.

Comment: Well...I turned the firewall off and that doesn't seem to make a difference. It seems to only be an issue the second I add the port #...as I can hit the URL with the firewall on if I ignore the port #

Comment: @skrilled Thanks for pointing me in the right direction !

Comment: Of course, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code actually works as intended...my issue was local firewall rules blocking remote connection to certain port #'s (as opposed to remote server firewall rules as skrilled suspected)